# Authenticating Oanda API for new market order in R

Tags: r, authentication

I'm trying to post a test order to Oanda and can't get the authentication to work.

```
require(RCurl)
require(jsonlite)

NewOrder <- function(AccountType,AccountID,Token,OrderType,Instrument,Units,Side) {


httpaccount <- "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com"


auth       <- c(Authorization = paste("Bearer",Token,sep=" "))
Queryhttp  <- paste(httpaccount,"/v3/accounts/",sep="")
Queryhttp1 <- paste(Queryhttp,AccountID,sep="")
Queryhttp2 <- paste(Queryhttp1,"/orders",sep="")

Param <- c(instrument=Instrument, units=Units, side=Side, type=OrderType)

PF <- postForm(Queryhttp2, style="POST", .params=Param,
               .opts=list(httpheader=auth))

InstJson <- fromJSON(PF, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

  return(InstJson)
}
```

When I run the function I receive the following message `Error: Bad Request`

Tracing the error back I can see that it seems to be the authentication thats causing the problem.

```
4.    stop(err) 
3.    stop.if.HTTP.error(http.header) 
2.    postForm(Queryhttp2, style = "POST", .params = Param, .opts = list(httpheader = auth)) 
1.    NewOrder(AccountType, AccountID = AccountID, Token = Token, OrderType = "market", 
      Instrument = "EUR_USD", Units = 20, Side = "buy")
```

I followed the API documentation but can't get it to work - Oanda documentation example:

```
body=$(cat << EOF
    {
      "order": {
        "price": "1.2000",
        "timeInForce": "GTC",
        "instrument": "EUR_CAD",
        "units": "10000",
        "clientExtensions": {
          "comment": "New idea for trading",
          "tag": "strategy_9",
          "id": "my_order_100"
        },
        "type": "MARKET_IF_TOUCHED",
        "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
      }
    }
    EOF
    )

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What packages are you using for functions like `postForm` that aren't part of base R?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm using `RCurl` and `jsonlite`. I added the dependencies to my questions as well.

Comment: try printing out your `Queryhttp2`

Comment: @chinsoon12 printing `Querryhhp2` returns `https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{my account number}/orders` which seems to be correct according to the API documentation which specifies `https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders`. I've updated my question with a more detail example given by Oanda.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work to create a market order on Oanda. You can modify it as needed to do different kinds of orders based on the Oanda API documentation.

```
URL_Orders<-'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{AccountID}/orders' #replace {AccountID} with the account ID for the account (no {}) 
Token<-{Token} #fill with API Token generated from Oanda (no {})

#create the body for the request 
req = list(   order = list(instrument="EUR_USD",
               units="1000", 
               type="MARKET",
               timeInForce="FOK",
               positionFill="DEFAULT"
               ) )

#format body as JSON 
body<-toJSON(req, auto_unbox = T, pretty = FALSE)

#post request 
Test<-httr::POST(URL_Orders, 
                 content_type_json(),
                 add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer ", Token)), 
                 body=body,
                 encode = "form",
                 verbose(data_out = TRUE, data_in = TRUE, info = TRUE))
```